# Using walkFileTree in a JavaScript source interpreted by rhino

Tags: java, rhino

If I do the following (JavaScript source):

```
Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get("somepath"), {
    visitFile: function(path, attr) {
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
});
```

I always get `Wrapped java.lang.NullPointerException: FileVisitor returned null`.

Some one have an idea how to solve this?

### Answer

As @SotiriosDelimanolis pointed, `FileVisitor` has other methods.

I was trying to `@Override` a method in `SimpleFileVisitor`, discovered that I could use `JavaAdapter`, [but I think there is a bug related to the mechanism of overriding classes](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=775566). So no way, we have to implement everything... :(

```
Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get("some/path"), {
    visitFile: function(path, attr) {
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    },
    preVisitDirectory: function() {
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    },
    visitFileFailed: function() {
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    },
    postVisitDirectory: function() {
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't know `rhino` at all, but the `FileVisitor` interface has other methods. Maybe `rhino` requires those.

Comment: I was trying to override SimpleFileVisitor. Discovered now that I could use JavaAdapter. But I got an error, and now I think its related to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mozilla-rhino/s1R791wF270/YllAxSHCJQgJ . Anyway, thank you.